# Link_to path for an object in a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, hyperlink

I'm creating a Rails app with two sets of nested models:

Goal -> Stage -> Template

Contact -> Tracker -> Email

On the show page for my Goal, I can list all the Trackers related to that Goal and display information such as the title but I can't work out how to link to the Tracker.

I've tried many variations of link_to but nothing seems to work so I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks so much!

The config Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/inbox'
  get 'pages/trackers'
  devise_for :users

  resources :contacts do
    resources :trackers do
      resources :emails
    end
  end
  resources :goals do
      resources :stages do
        resources :templates
      end
  end
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
 root "contacts#index"
end
```

My Goal Controller:

```
  def show
    @trackers = Tracker.all
    @tracker = Tracker.all
  end
```

My Goal Model:

```
class Goal < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stages , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trackers
end
```

My Tracker Model:

```
class Tracker < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :goal
  belongs_to :stage
  has_many :emails , dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is the Show.html.erb page for Goal with the wrong code for linking to the Tracker:

```
    <% for tracker in @goal.trackers %>
      <hr></hr>
            <%= link_to goal_tracker_path(@goal, tracker) do %> #Doesn't work
            <p><%= tracker.title %> | <%= tracker.contact.first_name %></p>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

Comment: Could you share the routes file? Or run `rails routes` and confirm that the path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tracker` resource is not nested to `goal` but to `contacts`. The path `goal_tracker_path (eg: /goals/1/trackers/1)` does not exist. Only `contact_tracker_path` exists. You can see this if you run `rails routes`.

There are couple ways you can go about this.

- Do away with the nesting. But this will not have a nested url structure. The path would be `/trackers/id`. The link to will look something like

```
link_to 'Title', tracker
```

- Nest tracker resource to goal as well. In this case, both `goal_tracker_path` and `contact_tracker_path` will be available though both will be using the same `TrackersController`. You could always write another controller and specify it in the routes if it's needed. The routes will look something like

```
resources :contacts do
    resources :trackers do
      resources :emails
    end
  end
  resources :goals do
      resources :trackers
      resources :stages do
        resources :templates
      end
  end
```

- Or you could just move the tracker resource to goals resource unless you would need `contact_tracker_path` as well.

It's best to always take a look at `rails routes` to make sure that the path exists.

Comment: Thanks @sajinmp - so I'll try the second option a try by adding resources :templates under resources :goals do. What would the correct link_to be in that case?

Comment: @CatMorley It would be `goal_tracker_path(goal, tracker)`. Alternatively `[goal, tracker]` should do the trick if I'm not wrong. You could run `rails routes` and make sure by checking the list of all routes.

Comment: Oh okay, that works but gives me an error on the tracker page: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TrackersController#show
Couldn't find Contact without an ID - do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: There is no contact being passed in this case. You seem to have already setup tracker controller in relation to contacts. Tracker can be fetched with `Tracker.find(id)` and goal and contact if needed can be fetched using `tracker.goal` and `tracker.contact`. It would help avoid needing 2 controllers, but it depends on the functionality intended. Another option is to have a seperate tracker controller. Max has explained it in his answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @sajinmp - I've managed to get this working now and have a much better understanding of how routing works!

Comment: Sorry yes, I have accepted it now - I didn't know about that until now! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Trackers are nested below contracts. Therefore, you need to pass the contract to which the tracker belongs to the `link_to` method too:

```
<% @goal.trackers.each do |tracker| %>
  <hr />
  <%= link_to [tracker.contact, tracker] do %>            
    <p><%= tracker.title %> | <%= tracker.contact.first_name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Or you might want to consider not using nesting in your routes that much. The official Rails Guides suggest [Shallow Nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) instead of nested routes.

Comment: There is no `goal_tracker_path` and this causes a fetch of `contact` records which apparently is only used to create a link.

Comment: @sajinmp: I fix the routing to avoid the unknown `goal_tracker_path` error. But when you want to avoid fetching the contact, then you need to change your routing and use shallow nesting, as I described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue that you're not actually nesting the `trackers` resource in `goals`.

To do so you would need:

```rb
resources :contacts do
  resources :trackers
  # ...
end

resources :goals do
  resources :trackers
  # ...
end
```

Here both `/contacts/1/trackers` and `/goals/1/trackers` will both go to the `TrackersContoller#index` method. One common way of handling this is what I call "the param sniffing method":

```rb
class TrackersContoller
  # GET /contacts/1/trackers
  # GET /goals/1/trackers
  # GET /trackers
  def index
    if params[:contact_id].present?
      @trackers = Contact.find(params[:contact_id]).trackers
    elsif params[:goal_id].present?
      @trackers = Goal.find(params[:contact_id]).trackers
    else
      @trackers = Tracker.all
    end
  end
 
  # ...
end
```

Which is pretty damn smelly as far as the Single Responsibity principle goes as the controller is now handling three different variations of a RESTful resource.

I generally prefer routing the nested representations of the resource to their own controller:

```rb
resources :trackers # TrackerController

resources :contacts do
  # routes to Contacts::TrackerContoller
  resources :trackers, only: [:new, :create, :index], 
                       module: :contacts
  # ...
end

resources :goals do
  # routes to Goals::TrackerContoller
  resources :trackers, only: [:new, :create, :index], 
                       module: :contacts
  # ...
end
```

```
module Contacts
  # Creates and lists trackers belonging to a Contact
  class TrackersContoller < ApplicationController
    # GET /contacts/1/trackers
    def index
      Contact.find(params[:contact_id]).trackers
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
module Goals
  # Creates and lists trackers belonging to a Goal
  class TrackersContoller < ApplicationController
    # GET /goals/1/trackers
    def index
      Goal.find(params[:goal_id]).trackers
    end
  end
end
```

Also before you go all crazy building a russian doll scheme you should probally read the [classic post by Jamis Buck about why deep nesting is a bad thing](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources):

> Rule of thumb: resources should never be nested more than 1 level
> deep. A collection may need to be scoped by its parent, but a specific
> member can always be accessed directly by an id, and shouldn’t need
> scoping (unless the id is not unique, for some reason).

The code may be highly dated but the basic tenets are just as relevant as they were 15 years ago. This is also recommended by the Rails guides.

Comment: Thanks so much @max - I'm regretting nesting another level but I have managed to get this working and understanding how routing works a lot better!